how to trim first two character when it contains specific string?
is there a way use a sql to query data as below example:
Source:
Name    Year
A2123   2000
A2456   2002
789     2003
4566    2020

My expected output:
Name   Year
123    2000
456    2002
789    2003
4566   2020

trim "A2" if name start with "A2"
thanks.

TRIM(LEADING 'AAA' FROM Name) maybe? WHat did you try?

The title says 'first two',  but example removes three characters.

sorry for my misleading, i would like to trim first two characters if it match specific value (not just alphabet characters). e.g. if name = A2888, i want to output 888, if name = 2888, i want to output 2888, if name = A2999, i want to output 999

If you want to trim the first two characters from the Name column for any string that starts with alphabetic characters, you can use a regular expression with the REGEXP_LIKE
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(Name, '^[A-Za-z]{2}') THEN SUBSTR(Name, 3)
        ELSE Name
    END AS Name,
    Year
FROM YourTable;


Thanks. But I just test it not works on oracle 9i. any other suggestion?

Assuming you want to strip one or more leading alphabet characters from the names, you could use REGEXP_REPLACE() with the regex pattern ^[A-Z]+:
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(Name, '^[A-Z]+', '') AS Name, Year
FROM yourTable;

